# How to run CGI script in web browser?

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

I am setting up environment for CGI script. For that I am following this link: http://help.cs.umn.edu/web/cgi-tutorial

I have written sample CGI script in my Ubuntu environment which is hosted in other server. I am connecting this server using PuTTY. I have successfully given permission to script file and directory. Now to test it, as mentioned in above link.

Below is the code of CGI script i have used:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI;

$cgi = new CGI();

print $cgi->header();

print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

print '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

        <title>Perl CGI test</title>
   </head>
  <body>';

print '
      <p>
         Hello world!
      </p>';


print '
   </body>

</html>
';
```

I am opening `http://www-users.cselabs.umn.edu/~ <your_username>/test-cgi.cgi` in my own system in Chrome and Firefox browsers.

Below error is displayed:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL  manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
www-users.cselabs.umn.edu
Thu Jun 11 01:56:35 2015
Apache.
```

How should I execute it successfully?

Note: CGI script is written on server which is accessed by PuTTY and WinSCP. And I am opening test URL on my own system i.e. windows in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Your script is in a wrong place or you use wrong url. Check path to script and server config.

Comment: Change this path `http://www-users.cselabs.umn.edu/~ /test-cgi.cgi` with your script path where you have hosted that.

Comment: @abhishek Are you actually hosting stuff on the `www-users.cselabs.umn.edu` server, or are you just blindly following the tutorial? You do know that you'll have to enter the address of the server on which you're hosting *your* script, right?

Comment: Also you need to have `cgid` module enabled in apache. It is not enabled by default. Although this is for later first you need to sort out your path thingy.

Comment: @serenesat: i have hosted script on some other ubuntu server and i am hitting URL in browser from my own system which is windows 7.

Comment: @Biffen: sorry sir, i have to correct my URL, it would be something like

"http://10.10.111.157/~<user_name>/test-cgi.cgi"

But now its showing unauthorized error, Since i have hosted it on root account of ubuntu server. Can you tell me what should i do ?

Comment: my script path on ubuntu server is "/root/.www/test-cgi.cgi"
what should i enter in browser so that that script would run

Comment: @abhishek Have you configured user directories for your web server? And have you given the files and directories involved the right permissions?

Comment: @biffien: Yes Sir, as per the tutorial. I have created ".www" directory and given required permission too. i.e. "chmod 700 test-cgi.cgi"

do we have to do any port forwarding settings?

Comment: And do we have to run apache server on my system (from which i am opening browser)

Comment: @abhishek I know too little about your setup, but port forwarding seems unlikely. If `test-cgi.cgi` is owned by root and the web server is run as some other user then 700 is incorrect. And make sure the permissions of the parent director(y|ies) are correct too. In the end the web server user must be able to read the file.

Comment: @abhishek Your latest comment makes it sound like you *really* should start with something else, e.g. learn how the web works.

Comment: That is a very bad tutorial, which you should not use as a guide.  [Try this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Tutorials#Web-Programming)

Comment: @Ron Bergin: Thanks Sir, I will follow that Tutorial.